# Problems after creating styles.xml v21

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'v created a new `styles.xml` file (v21) to implement material design for my app.
After i did that my app didn't worked because all my activities was extending `AppCompatActivity`. I'v changed them to extand `Activity` only and it fixed it but not all the activities, one of my activities is crushing.

Here is the stack trace of the exception that I receive:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xff00ff19 a=1}
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                                      at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:580)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1283)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xff00ff19 a=1}
                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6842)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.java:5779)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378) 
                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369) 
                                                                      at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:580) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715) 
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715) 
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1283) 
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am trying to solve this problem for 2 days already, but i cant understand where the problem is, and what is the problem.

Thx in advance!!

**values/styles.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

**v21/styles.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#8bced6</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#48696c</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#00ff19</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar" >

        </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: Try to add Theme.AppCompat.Light as parent theme in your style to test if this will resolve a problem with exception.

Comment: I have 2 `styles.xml` files, 1 is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and the second is android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar.

Comment: Show that 2 files please. Error on line 19 is a problem as I see. I would say this style does not have parent set at all.

Comment: I'v added the files above.
I'v deleted the `styles.xml` v21 and it is working, what is wrong with this file?

Answer (score 0):

I'v solved the problem:

The problem was that when i created the `styles.xml v21` I'v set the parent to be a new theme instead of making the parent to be the the old `styles.xml`.